# SQL Help, Using "AND" creates a blank table

Tags: sql

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why my code isn't running correctly. Everything works great until I add "AND". In short, I am trying to find the first 100 shows that start on 9/10/2017 at 20:00:00.

```
     SELECT   TOP (100) 
              CONVERT(char(10), DisplayName) AS "Display Name", 
              ChannelNumber, 
              CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 108) AS "Start Time",
              CONVERT(varchar, EndTime, 108) AS "End Time", 
              CONVERT(char(30), Title) AS Title

     FROM     all_data

     WHERE    OriginalAirDate = '9/10/2017'
              AND StartTime='20:00:00'

     ORDER BY ChannelNumber ASC;
```

Expected Results :

[image]

Comment: Could you give some sample data and expected result, and if you have error better put log error in your answer that will provide much better answer.

Comment: There is no error message. It executes fine. The table just becomes blank but only with the "AND" statement.

Comment: What's `StartTime` type and what's your dbms?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Most likely `OriginalAirDate` and `StartTime` are of type `DateTime` or one of them is of type `DateTime`. Cast them before making the comparison so use `cast(OriginalAirDate as Date) = ...` or to a time `cast(StartTime as Time)`

Comment: you need to put the start time value in the original format of your db data, it may not be the format of hh:mm:ss

Comment: the DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Thank you guys for your help. I am still trying to learn how to properly use functions like CONVERT and CAST. W3Ssschools didn't do too good of a job. Do you recommend a site for me to better understand SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'm taking a wild guess at what the problem is but I think it's to do with your converted datetime column (start date). You're trying to find something like `01/01/2018 20:00:00` but filtering on the time part alone which will return no results as no date AND time match just the time part. You need to perform the conversion again in your WHERE clause.

```
 SELECT   TOP (100) 
          CONVERT(char(10), DisplayName) AS "Display Name", 
          ChannelNumber, 
          CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 108) AS "Start Time",
          CONVERT(varchar, EndTime, 108) AS "End Time", 
          CONVERT(char(30), Title) AS Title

 FROM     all_data

 WHERE    OriginalAirDate = '9/10/2017'
          AND CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 108) = '20:00:00'

 ORDER BY ChannelNumber ASC;
```

Comment: this is my suspicion too.

Comment: That was exactly it. I am still a bit confused on how to properly use the CONVERT function. I thought since I already converted StartTime that conversion would carry over for the rest of the code. I am new to SQL and this type of programming.